# Adding Page number and new line after a border line in MS Word header by a VBA excel program

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a little problem with my vba program.

I have a program in VBA excel to create a new word document. I would like to add a Header in my word document, but I am new to VBA in word. So I don't know how to do it.

In my header, I would like to have some information from Excel on the left side and the page number " Page X of Y"  on the right side. One more thing, I was able to add a border line under my header, but I don't know how to add a extra line after the border to keep a space between header and normal text.

Here is my code:

```
Dim objword As Word.Application
Dim mydoc As Word.document
Dim WRng As Word.Range
Set objword = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set mydoc = objword.Documents.Add

'HEADER

Set WRng = mydoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

WRng.Text = wsexcel.Range("A5") & " " & wsexcel.Range("B5") & vbtab & **Page  number of total**
WRng.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

**???? Add space after the border line???**
```

Header example

[image: Header example]

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjpuG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following will create a space after the bottom border line in your header:

1) Increase the size of the top margin in the page layout/formatting. (This is the distance between the top edge of the paper and the first line of non-header text on the page.) 
2) In the paragraph formatting of the header text, increase the "spacing after" setting. Set the option for eliminating spacing between paragraphs of the same style or you might end up creating space between all the lines of your heading text.

You can do either of these in your VBA code.

Comment: Many thanks! I just add this following line to change the top margin and  It works! Many thanks again! I never though about margins. mydoc.Sections(1).PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(1.7)